# Run the PHP function with a preset interval

Tags: php

I would like to handle the following cases: When users receive an email alert for salary increase, they will have 3 days to enter the web for evaluation. If at that time they do not evaluate, after 3 days they will not be evaluated anymore. My problem is that I do not know what PHP function to use for this 3 day period. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two alternatives:

Both require you store the date/time when the email alert is sent in a table in a database where PHP can look for it.

**Proactive alternative:**

You setup a sort "Nightly Batch Job", using cron jobs on the server, to run once a day, where you check the date/time stored for each alert against the current date/time and you mark the past dew evaluations as closed. If a user submits an evaluation, and the evaluation mark is closed, the evalluation is rejected.

**The reactive alternative:**

You don't do any control before hand.
If the user decides to submit the evaluatio, you check the stored date when the alert was sent against the current date of the server, only for that user, and if the current date is inside the 3 day window, you process the evaluation, and if it isn't you reject it.